# LinkedIn: Login with LinkedIn JavaScript & PHP API

Tags: php, javascript, linkedin-api

i have implemented the authentication for my site with linkedin auth. I mean login with linkedin button using php oauth class. But could not get the email address. After that i have tried javascript. Even though i can't. it shown some errors.

So can anyone post or give idea to get email address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For version, V2 use this simple code.

```
<?php 

$config['callback_url']  =   ''; //Your callback URL

$config['Client_ID']   =   ''; // Your LinkedIn Application Client ID
$config['Client_Secret'] =   '';  // Your LinkedIn Application Client Secret 

?>




<?php
echo '<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id='.$config['Client_ID'].'&redirect_uri='.$config['callback_url'].'&state=98765EeFWf45A53sdfKef4233&scope=r_liteprofile r_emailaddress w_member_social"><img src="./images/linkedin_connect_button.png" alt="Sign in with LinkedIn"/></a>';  //Button code and scope url.
?>


<?php

if(isset($_GET['code'])) // get code after authorization
{

    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'; 
    $param = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$_GET['code'].'&redirect_uri='.$config['callback_url'].'&client_id='.$config['Client_ID'].'&client_secret='.$config['Client_Secret'];
    //$return = (json_decode(post_curl($url,$param),true)); // Request for access token


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //Remote Location URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Return data instead printing directly in Browser
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 7); //Timeout after 7 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //We add these 2 lines to create POST request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param); //parameters data
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $return = (json_decode($result,true));

    print_r($return);

    if($return['error']) // if invalid output error
    {
       $content = 'Some error occured<br><br>'.$return['error_description'].'<br><br>Please Try again.';
    }
    else // token received successfully
    {

        $url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=".$return['access_token'];
        //step1
        $cSession = curl_init();
        //step2
        curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        //step3
        $result = curl_exec($cSession);
        //step4
        curl_close($cSession);
        $return = (json_decode($result,true));
        print_r($return);

    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

email address is only available o the authenticated user

Make the following GET call to fetch the email address for the authenticated user:

GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)

i hope that will help you